# How do I get paintComponent(Graphics g) to call? repaint() won't work every time

Tags: java, swing, jframe, repaint, paintcomponent

The following in a Java SE6 program that is a tic tac toe game:

I have a class `MiniPanel` that extends `JPanel` that I have in a grid. If the user clicks one of these, a listener does some stuff then... eventually, it calls a method placeX() or placeO() on the MiniPanel that was clicked. That does some stuff then prints out a message saying that the method was called, and the very next line calls an animatePanel() method, which calls repaint() inside, printing out a message right before.

The class `MiniPanel` also overrides **`paintComponent(Graphics g)`** with a method that *first* prints out a message saying that paintComponent was called THEN does `super.paintComponent(g)` and then does other stuff.

The problem is that when I click a `MiniPanel`, the first 2 messages saying that `placeX()` or `placeO()` and animatePanel() was called appears, which means that `repaint()` *must* have been called. But `paintComponent(Graphics g)` is never called! Another weird thing is that it works if I call `placeX()` directly when the `MiniPanel` is initialized but not otherwise.

I only have `paintComponent(Graphics g)` overridden, nothing else.

Here is paintComponent:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        if (Controller.DEBUG) System.out.println("MiniPanel at ("+row+", "+col+") received paintComponent (is repainting now).");
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ...
        ...
    }
```

placeX (placeO is pretty much the same thing):

```
    public void placeX(){
    ...
    if (Controller.DEBUG) System.out.println("MiniPanel at ("+row+", "+col+") received placeX.");
    ...
    animatePanel();
}
```

animatePanel:

```
        private void animatePanel() {
    if (Controller.DEBUG) System.out.println("MiniPanel at ("+row+", "+col+") doing animatePanel().");
    timer.start();
}
```

The timer calls this repeatedly for a little animation:

```
        private ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (Controller.DEBUG) System.out.println("MiniPanel at ("+row+", "+col+") doing actionPerformed().");
        ...
        if (Controller.DEBUG) System.out.println("MiniPanel at ("+row+", "+col+") about to repaint... Should receive paintComponent command!");
        repaint();
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show relevant code (like the `paintComponent() methods`) for accurate and quick responses.

Comment: To avoid people guessing consider posting a shortened version of your code - [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Try putting `super.paintComponent(g)` as the first line.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.

Comment: It's not obvious from the code, but, try calling `repaint` on `MiniPanel` directly (rather then it's parent), also make sure that the reference to `MiniPanel` you are working on is actually is the one that is on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that I should make a repaint() method in MiniPanel that just calls super.repaint() and call that? I tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: Ah, solved it myself. I have to call setVisible(true) on the JPanel holding all of these to make repaint() call paintComponent(Graphics g). Calling setVisible(true) on the individual MiniPanels does not work. So what I've heard about repaint() ALWAYS calling paintComponent(Graphics g) is false!